# Strapi error: entityManager.findOneWithCreatorRoles is not a function

Tags: typescript, strapi

I have `categories` (left) and `menus` (right) collection types as shown in the image below.
[image: https://d38xoolefqxt5u.cloudfront.net/optimized/3X/0/4/04957241957a371ef8f15f02f69989dce15cb01e_2_1035x394.png]

The `categories` and `menus` collection types have this type of relation.
[image: ![image|690x339](upload://mkxjFihYguD38BQMYvL3sYqzcCh.png)]

The `author` role could only CRUD the `categories` and `menu` data they created.
But when I tried to sign in using one of the author accounts and then click on the `category` field, I could see all categories from the database (not only the data created by the current author).
[image: ![image|690x289](upload://9q5YeznMU2quP7knPUI10AdAMh0.png)]

I searched on the internet and found the same issue here https://forum.strapi.io/t/author-is-reading-other-authors-items-by-the-related-field/2920.
Then I implemented this solution https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/7696#issuecomment-1371858927 in Typescript.
When I ran the Strapi and then clicked on the `category` field on the one `menu` content (like the image above), the Strapi returned this error `error: entityManager.findOneWithCreatorRoles is not a function`.

**Question: how to fix the error above?**

I didn't know if my approach below was correct or not.
I searched on the internet about the error and didn't find any.
Then I searched `entityManager`on the Strapi Github repository and found the `entity-manager.ts` file https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/develop/packages/core/content-manager/server/src/services/entity-manager.ts.
I copied and pasted the file into the same folder as the `entity-manager.ts` file (`src` -> `content-manager` -> `entity-manager.ts`)

But the error still appeared.

System Information:

- Strapi Version: 4.15.5 with Typescript
- Operating System: Windows 11
- Database: Postgres
- Node Version: 18.19.0
- NPM Version: 10.2.3
- Yarn Version: 1.22.19